# Textarea seems to be converting plain text to html entities

Tags: text-formatting

I have a textarea field (which i'm using to paste some custom CSS for a page) that has no formatting set on it.

However, when I paste the following in;

```
h2 {background-color: #03c7e1;}
```

ExpressionEngine automatically outputs it as;

```
h2 {background-color: #03c7e1;&#125;}
```

It's real confusing and wondered if anyone else had this issue before?

Comment: What's the field set to - none, xhtml... ?

Comment: It's set to 'none' :/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check the particular Channels preferences

admin > channel administration > channels >

Edit the preferences for the channel in question and look for "Channel Posting Preferences" and in particular "Default HTML formatting in channel entries" - set this to: "Allow ALL HTML".  I suspect it may be set to: "Convert HTML into characters entities"

Comment: Thanks Stuart. Seems it was already set to "All ALL HTML". :/

Answer (score 0):

`&#125;` is the HTML character entity for a right curly bracket `}`. It could be that you've forgotten to include a closing curly bracket somewhere in the code you're pasting in and it's being interpreted incorrectly as a result. Check your code in that textarea and ensure all brackets are paired up correctly.

If everything matches up correctly in your textarea field then it might well be in your template where a mis-match is causing the issue.